# Duplicate class com.google.zxing.Binarizer found in modules jetified-com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar and jetified-core-3.3.3.jar

Tags: android, angular, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework

So I tried running `ionic cordova run android` but I get a build failed with an exception.

> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.Binarizer found in modules jetified-com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar (com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar) and jetified-core-3.3.3.jar (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap found in modules jetified-com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar (com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar) and jetified-core-3.3.3.jar (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.ChecksumException found in modules jetified-com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar (com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar) and jetified-core-3.3.3.jar (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.DecodeHintType found in modules jetified-com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar (com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar) and jetified-core-3.3.3.jar (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.EncodeHintType found in modules jetified-com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar (com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar) and jetified-core-3.3.3.jar (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.FormatException found in modules jetified-com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar (com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar) and jetified-core-3.3.3.jar (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.LuminanceSource found in modules jetified-com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar (com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar) and jetified-core-3.3.3.jar (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader found in modules jetified-com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar (com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar) and jetified-core-3.3.3.jar (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter found in modules jetified-com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar (com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar) and jetified-core-3.3.3.jar (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter$1 found in modules jetified-com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar (com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar) and jetified-core-3.3.3.jar (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.NotFoundException found in modules jetified-com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar (com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar) and jetified-core-3.3.3.jar (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.PlanarYUVLuminanceSource found in modules jetified-com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar (com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar) and jetified-core-3.3.3.jar (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.RGBLuminanceSource found in modules jetified-com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar (com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar) and jetified-core-3.3.3.jar (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.Reader found in modules jetified-com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar (com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar) and jetified-core-3.3.3.jar (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)

*And the list goes on and finishes with :*

> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder.QRCode found in modules jetified-com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar (com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar) and jetified-core-3.3.3.jar (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
>
> Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency
> resolution errors.
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
> incompatible with Gradle 7.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
> individual deprecation warnings. See
> https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

**Here is my build.gradle file :**

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
repositories repos

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
  }

allprojects {
    apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
    repositories repos

project.ext {
  defaultBuildToolsVersion="29.0.2" //String
  defaultMinSdkVersion=22 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 5.1
  defaultTargetSdkVersion=29 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
  defaultCompileSdkVersion=29 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I Tried :

1. Adding : `configurations {compile.exclude group: 'com.google.zxing'}` to build.gradle
2. removed the android platform from cordova and then adding it.
3. removed the barcodescanner plugin then adding it.

I have been stuck with this one for almost a week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused because of a conflict between facebook4 plugin and barcodeScanner plugin. Both use a library called ZXing which will cause a conflict.

The easy fix (hard to find) was to remove the facebook plugin and add the same one without the zxing library.

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save --variable APP_ID="ID" --variable APP_NAME="NAME"
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/AndreiTelteu/cordova-plugin-facebook4-no-zxing --save --variable APP_ID="ID" --variable APP_NAME="NAME"
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova platform rm android
```

This fixed my problem. Note that there is nothing to edit in your code.

Check the git repo for more info: https://github.com/AndreiTelteu/cordova-plugin-facebook4-no-zxing

Comment: cordova-plugin-facebook4 is no longer maintained. I'd recommend checking cordova-plugin-facebook-connect.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to remove `implementation files('libs/core.jar')` from my `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ..........
    implementation files('libs/core.jar') // Remove this line
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:latest.release' // Conflicting with libs/core.jar.
    ..........
}
```

[image]