# ionic build give Duplicate class found

Tags: android, angular, gradle, ionic-framework

I built my ionic project, when running it shows me this error in build output

```
Duplicate class com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder.Encoder$1 found in modules jetified-barcodescanner-release-2.1.5-runtime (:barcodescanner-release-2.1.5:) and jetified-core-3.4.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.4.0)
Duplicate class com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder.MaskUtil found in modules jetified-barcodescanner-release-2.1.5-runtime (:barcodescanner-release-2.1.5:) and jetified-core-3.4.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.4.0)
Duplicate class com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder.MatrixUtil found in modules jetified-barcodescanner-release-2.1.5-runtime (:barcodescanner-release-2.1.5:) and jetified-core-3.4.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.4.0)
Duplicate class com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder.QRCode found in modules jetified-barcodescanner-release-2.1.5-runtime (:barcodescanner-release-2.1.5:) and jetified-core-3.4.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.4.0)
```

Comment: If you use facebook4 plugin, this can be a solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/68755026